# iOS iPhone Safari freezes and is unresponsive

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, bug, mobile-safari

Safari on my iPhone is completely unusable. It opens fine but when I try to visit an address it freezes. The loading bar sticks at maybe 10%.

This happens with any address I type or any search query I make. I have to quit the app to be able to try again.

Actions taken:
* Clear safari browsing data
* Reset iPhone settings
* Erase settings and content and restore from iCloud backup

I guess the next step would be to erase settings and content and not restore. I'm reluctant to do this as I don't want to lose everything.

Is there any other step I can try to get Safari working?

I'm using iOS 8.3. (I've read that this was a bug with 8.2, so I'm surprised I'm experiencing this issue and it's not been completely fixed)

Comment: The long way would be test both - erase without restore, test, erase & restore, test. At least then you'd have a better clue where the root cause may lie.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, and Safari is working fine in the non-restored version. So it's something somewhere in my saved settings.

Comment: just a guess - do you have any non-Apple keyboard replacement?

Comment: No, used to but deleted it a while ago.

Comment: hmm… sorry, I'm running out of ideas - wish you luck….see if anybody else has something.

Comment: I’m experiencing the exact same issue on 8.4.1. Though it doesn’t happen with all websites. It does seem that sites with a slower response time are more inclined to freeze Safari.